# set radio button (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I am retrieving data from the database using the Ajax call. Based on the data in the DB radio button is checked on UI. For the first ajax call, the radio button is being checked. And from the next ajax call sometimes the radio button is being checked and sometimes not being checked.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "{% url 'folder1:db-xxxx' %}",
    data: {url: urlVal, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
    success: function(data, xhr, textStatus) {

         for (j = 0; j < data[1].length; j++)
         {      
             status = data[3][j].status.toLowerCase()

            var row4 =   $('<tr class="rowcl" id="tr3"><td></td><td>Status</td><td></td><td><input type="radio" name="status"  value="Active" id="active'+j+'" class="edt"/>Active&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="status"  value="Inactive" id="inactive'+j+'" class="edt"/>Inactive<input type="radio" name="status"  value="Notdetermined" id="notdetermined'+j+'" class="edt"/>Cannot be determined</td></tr>');

            row4.insertBefore($('#row3'));
            console.log(status+j);
           $( "#"+status+j).prop( "checked", true )
         }

         console.log(xhr);
         console.log(textStatus);
    },
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, error){
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
        alert('Some error occurred!');
    }
});
```

Object(1)
​
0: 
​
length: 1
​
: Object { jquery: "3.3.1", constructor: w()
, length: 0, …

Object(1)
​
0: 
​
length: 1
​
: Object { jquery: "3.3.1", constructor: w()
, length: 0, … }

InActive 
{}
​
: Object { jquery: "3.3.1", constructor: w(), length: 0, … }

Comment: can you post the result of console.log($( "#"+status+counter)) ?

Comment: A side note: the value of an id must be unique on whole page. According your code there will exists more than one html element with id 'tr3'.

Comment: @user11165861 Please put the content of your comment into the question. You can do that by clicking on the edit link underneath your question. After that delete your comment.

Comment: I removed id from tr. Still facing the same issue